# Push Notification for Nokia nid using c#

Tags: c#, push, nokia

i am working to sent a push message to Nokia phone from my c# project and i already put all the variables needed in my code but i handle an error Bad Request, i didn't understand its reason.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        //notification ID string i will get i from OVI
        notID = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(notID);
        string url = "https://alpha.one.ovi.com/nnapi/1.0/nid/" +(notID);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServiceId, service_secret);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request_parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request_parameters);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(request_parameters);
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
                MessageBox.Show("response=========" + sr.ReadToEnd());
                sr.Close();
                resStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("message====" + response.StatusCode);

            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following project: https://projects.forum.nokia.com/dotnet_notifications_api

It is a .NET wrapper for the Nokia Notifications API.